# broad scrapy crawl passing parameter (with different value each request) to callback with rule

Tags: scrapy

I've spent a lot of time playing around and using google but I could not solve my problem.

The below code is working, but I want to pass parameter/argument into `parse item` . How can I do that with rules?

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
import mysql.connector
from scrapy.http import Request
class FirstSpider(CrawlSpider):

name = 'firstspider'

def start_requests(self):
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password = 'root', host= 'localhost', database = 'Eistee')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    query = ("SELECT Domain, CompanyName FROM Crawlbydomain LIMIT 300, 100")

    cursor.execute(query)

    results = cursor.fetchall()

    for result in results:
        urlrequest = 'http://'+result[0]
        yield Request(urlrequest)

rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('.ch', )), callback='parse_item', follow= True),)

def parse_item(self, response):

    filename = response.url.translate(None, './')
    open(filename, 'wb').write(response.body)

parse_start_url = parse_item
```

How can I successfully pass parameters with new values each request to `parse_item` that can be carried to Rule?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the parameters in the `Rule`?

Comment: I'm trying to pass in a specific text to scrape. This text is varying coming from a database or textfile. I have no problem getting the text out of the database. But I cannot pass it into the crawler. I want something like: parse_item(self, response, args) that Rule can pick up